# Laravel Spatie Permissions Get a user resource with their roles and permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-api, laravel-permission, laravel-resource

I am writing because I have spent hours of testing looking for a solution to a problem and I still have not found how to solve it. I am using [Spatie Laravel Permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction) and it happens that I have 3 resources, one for `user`, another for `role` and another for `permissions`. I show the structure of the mentioned resources:

UserResource.php

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'roles' => RoleResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('roles')),
            'permissions' => PermissionResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('permissions', $this->getAllPermissions())),
            'active' => $this->active,
        ];
    }
}
```

RoleResource.php

```
class RoleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'permissions' => PermissionResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('permissions'))
        ];
    }
}
```

PermissionResource.php

```
class PermissionResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see in my `UserResource.php` file, I am defining a structure to display user roles and permissions only when required. You can also see that in the `permissions` key, I am not returning only the permissions associated with the user, I am returning all the permissions directly associated with the user and associated with the roles they have `getAllPermissions()`.

Now look at the `RoleResource.php` file, I am defining that the permissions associated with the role will be displayed only when necessary, and here is my problem. When I do the following:

```
public function index()
{
    return UserResource::make(User::with(['roles', 'permissions'])->find(1));
}
```

I am getting the following response:

[image: imagen]

Look at the key: `roles`, It is showing me the `permissions` relation, and that is not the expected result, I expect it to show me that result only when I do the following:

```
public function index()
{
    return UserResource::make(User::with(['roles.permissions', 'permissions'])->find(1));
}
```

I've been doing a lot of testing and everything seems to indicate that when I call the method `getAllPermissions()` also load the `permissions` relation and that is why this is happening. Please could you help me with this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. The only difference is that I only wanted to load 1 role since my users will only ever have one role. How I got around it was:

In UserResource.php

```
$user = [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'role' => $this->roles[0]->name,
];

if ($this->relationLoaded('permissions')) {
    $user['permissions'] = PermissionResource::collection($this->getAllPermissions());
}

return $user;
```

And then in UserController.php:

```
new UserResource(User::load('permissions')->get());
```

I don't know if this is correct but it's the only way I currently found to get around this issue. This works for me because I always want to only see the role name of my user. I guess for your problem you could use the same check in your RoleResource.php `$this->relationLoaded('roles.permissions')`